# How to write CSV data to JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing some JavaScript Google map API work. For particular line in JavaScript need to write .csv file data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Filed Inspection</title>


    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCoQ7Rdy6BwJBKnQBRML8xaidQNRuNnb5c"
      type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
    </script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var regionlocation = [];
        var markers = [];
        var iterator = 0;
        var areaiterator = 0;
        var map;
        var infowindow = [];
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        $(document).ready(function () {
            setTimeout(function() { initialize(); }, 400);
        });

        function initialize() {  

            infowindow = [];
            markers = [];
            GetValues();
            iterator = 0;
            areaiterator = 0;
            region = new google.maps.LatLng(regionlocation[areaiterator].split(',')[0], regionlocation[areaiterator].split(',')[1]);
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Map"), { 
                zoom: 20,
                 mapTypeId: 'satellite',
                center: region,
            });
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
            var center = map.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            map.setCenter(center); 
});
            drop();
        }

        function GetValues() {  
            regionlocation= ['-27.504021,151.961933','-27.505824,151.960922','-27.503617,151.963881','-27.508709,151.963534','-27.508315,151.957255','-27.50839,151.957856'];                      
            var ar=[];
            ar.push(regionlocation);
            var chunk;
            while (ar.length > 0) {
                chunk = ar.splice(0,2)
                console.log(chunk)
            }           
        }

        function drop() {
            for (var i = 0; i < regionlocation.length; i++) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    addMarker();
                }, 800);
            }
        }

        function addMarker() {
            var address = regionlocation[areaiterator];

            var icons = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
            var templat = regionlocation[areaiterator].split(',')[0];
            var templong = regionlocation[areaiterator].split(',')[1];
            var temp_latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(templat, templong);

            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: temp_latLng,
                map: map,
                icon: icons,
                draggable: false
            }));

            iterator++;
            areaiterator++;
        }


    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="Map" style="width: 2000px; height: 329px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Regionlocation Array contains list of Latitude and logitude. Am reading lat & longs from CSV file and need to write to javascript file.

I am reading CSV file using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>  
        <title>Pole Cleansing</title> 

        <style>
            .button {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <P>
        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" class="button" />
        <input class="button" type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" onclick = "upload()" />
    </p>

    <script type = "text/javascript" > 
    function upload(){
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");  
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;  
    if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {  
        if (typeof(FileReader) != "undefined") {  
            var reader = new FileReader();  
            reader.onload = function(e) {  
                var table = document.createElement("table");  
                var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");  
                for (var i = 1; i < rows.length-1; i++) {  
                    var row = table.insertRow(-1);  
                    var cells = rows[i].split(",");  
                    for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {  
                        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);  
                        cell.innerHTML = cells[j];  
                    }  
                }  
                var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");  
                dvCSV.innerHTML = "a";  
                dvCSV.appendChild(table);  
            }  
            reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);  
        } else {  
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");  
        }  
    } else {  
        alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");  
    }  
} 
</script>  
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use to read the csv file and brief when do you read the file (onload, button click etc)?

Comment: Aruna, I have added both code, badly need this. I just want to add data to array line(regionlocation) with CSV data in javascript file

Comment: any luck Aruna !!!!

Comment: Are you reading from one file and need to update in another file's js? Does the second file has any link to the first file (I mean, iframe, popup etc) or are they both completely not link to each other?

Comment: They are not linked, I am new to Javascript. I need to integrate. Step 1: Need to read two column of Latitude and Longitude. Step 2: Write that data directly into Javascript file (above on regionlocation = [] array line)

Comment: what server side language you used? Once you parse the csv data, you have to send it to the server and you can store as a `.json` file in the server side. Then from the second file, you can use ajax to directly read the `.json` file.

Comment: I am not suing any server side part. Just want create html file which has array data which we read (replace existing data) from csv file.

Comment: Sorry, without server interaction, you can't do this then. Pages without server interaction is treated as static pages and not dynamic.