# R/ Shiny read csv as data and make some if-then-else statement and show the results?

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I am not sure if it makes sense. But I am looking for some help with using Shiny. Here is what I need, first, read some csv file on the shiny server. Second, by clicking a button as an if-then-else statement proceeds each observation's value of data sorted somehow.

csv:

```
no,money,penalty
1,10000,1000
2,20000,1000
3,30000,2000
```

if-then-else statement:

```
if money >10000 then 1 else 0
if penalty >1000 then 1 else 0
```

here is the r-shiny code I am working on:

```
# Load packages
library(shiny)

if (interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
        accept = c(
          "text/csv",
          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
          ".csv")
        ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Thank you for your help ahead.

Comment: is it possible without using r-shiny but just using html?? thx

Comment: could you please give us a minimal example shinyApp code with ui and server that is somewhat remotly to that what you want. It is very hard to do something otherwise

Comment: I added what you mean

Comment: OK but now you have to explain in simple English what should happen when you press the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken below df as an example

```
df <- data.frame(no =c(1:3),money=c(9999:10001),penalty=c(999:1001))
```

Below is the complete code which will work if you input any file with column names like the above df

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),actionButton("sort","Do Sorting")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents"),tableOutput("sortedcontents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  rawInputData = reactive({
    rawData = input$file1


    if(!is.null(rawData)) {
      data = read.csv(rawData$datapath);
    } else {
      return(NULL);
    }

  });


  output$contents <- renderTable({
    newData = rawInputData()  
    if(is.null(newData))
      return();
    newData;
  })

  sorting = reactive({
    if(input$sort){
      newData = rawInputData()
      newData$moneysort <- ifelse(newData$money >=10000, 1, 0)
      newData$penaltysort <- ifelse(newData$penalty >=1000, 1, 0)
       }
    newData

  })
  output$sortedcontents <- renderTable({
    newData = sorting()  
    if(is.null(newData))
      return();
    newData;
  })

}


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you are looking something like this, let me know I can fine tune it a bit.

Comment: Thank you. this is what I exactly wanted!

Comment: So sorry for the late response

Comment: Btw, is it possible on the html?

Comment: As in you want to do the same operation but the button should be on HTML page, and when you click that button the above operations should happen. Is this what you want?

Comment: thank you for fast response. I mean if I making this procedure only on html without using R/shiny, can you say it is possible? I found reading csv in html script whose link is as below.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902556/how-to-write-csv-data-to-javascript-file)

Comment: Not an expert in HTML but HTML is for front end.So yes, you can design a page in HTML where you can see the data and there will be a button which you press can do certain modifications. But the modifications has to be done somewhere, so a database where these modifications needs to be done should be integrated with HTML

Comment: Thanks again for the fast response! Then, you mean there can be possible to read csv file and use if-else statement for the data I put on the html?

Comment: Again HTML will only help in showcasing the file, as it is just front end. You will need javascript/R/Python to read the csv file.